# Outbound link tracking not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to track events in Google analytics for outbound links and it doesn't seem to be working. Links that don't take you off the site work fine but not the outbound links. I'm attaching the javascript to the onclick event

```
onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', {
eventCategory: 'Magazine',
eventAction: 'Tutorial Files',
eventLabel: '<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>', 
transport: 'beacon'
});"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of gotchas around proper outbound link tracking, the most common one being that most browsers stop executing JavaScript on the current page once a request has started for the next page.

That means the code in your `onclick` handler is often not even going to run, which is why it's not working.

The easiest solution I can recommend is to use the [analytics.js autotrack plugins](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack), which do outbound link tracking for you.

If you want to code the implementation yourself, you can look at the autotrack [outboundLinkTracker source code](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/0.6.5/lib/plugins/outbound-link-tracker.js) to see how it handles all of the gotchas.

Comment: I kind of had a feeling that's was the case here but the documentation says to use beacon as the transport method for these outbound links so I was really optimistic about it working.

Comment: Beacon does work, but it's not supported in all browsers, so if you want accurate reporting, you have to use a fallback as well. That's what autotrack does if you look at the code.